# Interactive Entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Is it possible to have 2 entry widgets that are interactive, I'm thinking about conversions here, so for example Miles to Kilo-meters & vice-versa; as I enter data into one widget, it is automatically updated in the other widget, regardless of which one I start with.

Below is my starting point, but I need the entry widgets to be sensitive to "Key" and call a respective function?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Conversions")
root.geometry("500x200")

ent_pound = Entry(root, width=20)
ent_pound.grid(row=0,column=0)

ent_kilo = Entry(root, width=20)
ent_kilo.grid(row=1,column=0)

value_pound=eval(ent_pound.get())
ent_kilo.delete(0,END)
ent_kilo.insert(0,repr(value*0.453592))

value_kilo=eval(ent_kilo.get())
ent_pound.delete(0,END)
ent_pound.insert(0,repr(value/0.453592))
`
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using Tkinter variables. You can create a `DoubleVar` for each entry, then add a trace to call a function on write. The variables are then bound to the entries with the `textvariable` attribute.

You can then use the `get` and `set` methods of the variables to do the conversion. The conversion is wrapped in a try/except to ignore the error from `get` if the entry is empty.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Conversions")
root.geometry("500x200")

pound_var = DoubleVar()
kilo_var = DoubleVar()

def set_kilo(*args):
    try:
        value = pound_var.get()
        kilo_var.set(value*0.453592)
    except: pass

def set_pound(*args):
    try:
        value = kilo_var.get()
        pound_var.set(value/0.453592)
    except: pass

pound_var.trace_add("write", set_kilo)
ent_pound = Entry(root, width=20, textvariable = pound_var)
ent_pound.grid(row=0,column=0)

kilo_var.trace_add("write", set_pound)
ent_kilo = Entry(root, width=20, textvariable = kilo_var)
ent_kilo.grid(row=1,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

If you don't like how `DoubleVar` prefills the entry, you could use `StringVar` instead and convert the input

```
pound_var = StringVar()
kilo_var = StringVar()

def set_kilo(*args):
    try:
        value = float(pound_var.get())
        kilo_var.set(value*0.453592)
    except: pass

def set_pound(*args):
    try:
        value = float(kilo_var.get())
        pound_var.set(value/0.453592)
    except: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this with your entry widget:

```
def on_entry_key_press(event):
    # Your code here


entry.bind("<Key>", on_entry_key_press)
```

Here, `on_entry_key_press` is a method that will call when any key is pressed while `entry` is focused. Remember, you have to bind your entry before place/pack/grid. And if you want to get which key is pressed, then you can get that by `event.char`.